# How can I use nodemon without using npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

My network doesn't allowed using `npm install`. 
How can I install and use nodemon? Node run only after set PATH variables on windows I tried set the path for nodemon, but I dont have results.

Comment: go to https://github.com/remy/nodemon and download it directly?

Comment: @ssbb And then download all dependencies **recursively**? Oh my gosh... Find a cafe, bookstore or anywhere, use `npm install`, and go back to your place to work... What a sad story.

Comment: I've the zip files from github

Comment: @Leo well , i'm ok it's not the finest, but without npm i supose that dl zip is the best way.?

Comment: @flpms open the `package.json`, you need to download all dependencies, and every dependency's dependencies, and on and on and on...

Comment: Have you tried communicating with your network to get npm allowed? it's a pretty fundamental part of node.js development..

Comment: Like previous comments - when faced with similar issues, I first contact network team to help me resolve the issue. If they cannot/refuse to help, I go to my manager, declare that I cannot perform my duties because of X and company is losing money. Usually that gets things moving pretty fast.

Comment: Ask your firewall team to allow it access, if they say no, it maybe that what your doing isn't relevant to that company?

Comment: digwig: It's a huge company and I work as consultant, so is more complicated than that.

@KevinB. I can't be more detailed, but they ignored that, sadly.

Comment: If you do have access to GIT within the network, an alternative would be to build the application outside the network and commit the node_modules folder with the the repository. then, you would just need to do an npm rebuild to get going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to install an npm package is going to be to either tunnel out of your network with a proxy, or to simply install the package while you're on a different network. The reason it's not as simple to just download it is that npm packages have a list of dependencies that need to be installed along with it. Npm takes care of installing the dependency graph for you. If you try to install it manually you would have to manually go over nodemon's `package.json` file and install all of its dependencies. That might not be so bad until you realize that you then have to go through all those dependencies and install *their* dependencies, and so on...

I'm not at all affiliated with [IPVanish](https://www.ipvanish.com/) but I recently signed up for their service for the same reason as you. My computer has a VPN configured that connects to an IPVanish server and then my computer tunnels all internet traffic through that VPN. It's nice for simple anonymous web browsing, but more importantly there is no way for network admins here to see where any of my traffic is going. To them it appears that I'm just talking to a random server. They'd have to block every single IPVanish server (and there's a lot!).

There are other alternatives but that one had good reviews and it's only $10 a month. I haven't tried any others but I'm sure they're just as good.

---

If tunneling out of your network or installing the module on a different network isn't an option, I'm happy to install it myself and upload a zip of the completed install to Google Drive so you can just extract it to the global npm folder. However, that would obviously not be a permanent solution for you and even though I have good intentions, you don't know me and I don't recommend downloading random stuff off of a stranger's Google Drive.

I recommend getting a friend to do the following from another network:

1. Install nodemon: `npm install -g nodemon`
2. Find where global npm modules install to: `npm config get prefix`
3. Navigate to the global npm module path, find the nodemon directory, and zip it up.
4. Email/Dropbox you the archived module.
5. On your machine figure out where global npm modules install to: `npm config get prefix`
6. Extract the nodemon zip to that location.